# Graphql query error ! variable is declared but never used

Tags: javascript, react-native, shopify, graphql-js, react-apollo

I'm trying to fetch Shopify products on the basis of search keyword.

I tested this query by passing hard coded value in the query it works fine but I need to pass variable value so in that case it gives an error that

> Grapghql query error searchKeyword is declared but not used.

Here is my query to search products on the basis of `title`, `tag` and `product_type`.

Unsuccessful case:

```
export const searchProductsQuery = gql` query($searchKeyword: String!){
    shop {
        products(first: 10, query:"title:'$searchKeyword' OR tag:'$searchKeyword' OR product_type:'$searchKeyword'") {
            edges {
                cursor
                node {
                    id
                    title
                    handle
                    description
                    productType
                    images(first: 5) {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                id
                                src
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    variants(first: 5) {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                id
                                title
                                price
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`;
```

Successful case:

```
export const searchProductsQuery = gql` query{
shop {
     products(first: 10, query:"title:'games' OR tag:'games' OR product_type:'games'") {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables you define for your operation are just that -- variables. They cannot be used like a template literal placeholder, which is what you are trying to do.

In GraphQL, variables can only be used as input for an argument. For example, `query` is an argument that takes a (non-null) String. So, we can create a variable like `$mySearchQuery`, set it to `"title:'games' OR tag:'games' OR product_type:'games'"` and then use it like this:

```
products(query:$mySearchQuery)
```

If you have a javascript variable that you want to use as part of `$mySearchQuery`, you can set the value you pass in for `$mySearchQuery` inside your javascript code by using a template literal:

```
const options = {
  variables: {
    mySearchQuery: `title:'${keyword}' OR tag:'${keyword}' OR product_type:'${keyword}'`
  }
}
```

You are seeing an error that your variable was declared and never used because it never was -- the references to it inside your query are part of a string and therefore are parsed literally.

Comment: Thanks Daniel your answer solved my problem, query is working now.