# GraphQL query error -- variable is never used in operation

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am performing a request for an individual post from Apollo Server / Express backend.

In the Apollo GraphQL sandbox, the query works and retrieves the correct post, however, the query has a red squiggle identifying an error which reads -

> Variable "$getPostId" is never used in operation "Query".

The query is as follows -

```
query Query($getPostId: ID!) {
  getPost(id:"20c9b3ac-afe6-4faa-a3f9-e00ef1b38ccf") {
    title
    author
    id
  }
}
```

The schema is as follows -

```
module.exports = gql`
  type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    author: String!
  }
  type Query {
    getPosts: [Post]!
    getPost(id: ID!): Post
  }
  ...
`
```

The closest post which seems to address a similar problem I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488163/graphql-query-error-variable-is-declared-but-never-used). However, I can't translate the resolution to my problem.

Why is the error showing (particularly when the query runs successfully)? What needs to be done to stop the error from showing?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like

```
query Query($getPostId: ID!) {
  getPost(id:"20c9b3ac-afe6-4faa-a3f9-e00ef1b38ccf") {
    title
    author
    id
  }
}
```

is supposed to be

```
query Query($getPostId: ID!) {
  getPost(id: $getPostId) {
    title
    author
    id
  }
}
```

Or if your query is actually meant to hard-code the ID, then you want

```
query Query {
  getPost(id:"20c9b3ac-afe6-4faa-a3f9-e00ef1b38ccf") {
    title
    author
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. The first solution is what I was after. For testing in the sandbox I found the variables feature which helped as well.